# Stylus to pure CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, stylus

I want to translate a code from Stylus into pure CSS,because i don't know Stylus and the documentation doesn't really help much..
Here is the code,thanks in advance

```
 &:first-of-type
      left 0
      transform rotate(45deg)

    &:last-of-type
      right 0
      transform rotate(-45deg)

  &.active

    span
      &:first-of-type
        transform rotate(-45deg)

      &:last-of-type
        transform rotate(45deg)
```

Comment: SO is not a coding service - it's here to help coding problems

Comment: There are converters online: http://stylus-lang.com/try.html#?code=%26%3Afirst-of-type%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20left%200%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20transform%20rotate(45deg)%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%26%3Alast-of-type%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20right%200%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20transform%20rotate(-45deg)%0A%0A%20%20%26.active%0A%0A%20%20%20%20span%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%3Afirst-of-type%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20transform%20rotate(-45deg)%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%3Alast-of-type%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20transform%20rotate(45deg)

Answer (score 1):

It's actually described very well on the [Stylus Github page](https://github.com/stylus/stylus/)

> **Installation**
>
> `npm install stylus -g`
>
> **Basic Usage**
>
> Watch and compile a stylus file from command line with
>
> `stylus -w style.styl -o style.css`

The GitHub page was linked directly by the [stylus documentation](http://stylus-lang.com/) you said you read.
Please check more thoroughly before you ask a question next time, it will save you time and rep :)